# How can citizens prevent brainwashing?

Tags: internal-consistency, virtual-reality, illusion

I need to identify a way citizens can prevent brainwashing, or acertain a level of clarity about reality when propaganda is abundant.

What systems exist that would allow for a sincere search for truth?

Comment: Education?  This is a tricky question to answer because every culture has some level of clarity about reality and every culture has the topics which they are "brainwashed" about, so there's no real evidence of any system overcoming this.  Likewise, there's no real evidence for a system which doesn't overcome this.

Comment: How is brainwashing taking place? Before we know that we cannot tell about methods to prevent it.

Comment: So what is brainwashing? I ask because people use axioms or dogma all the time, and some people think that at least one axiom (or dogmatic expression) is needed to solve problems like "do I exist?" Are axioms or some dogma "brainwashing"?

Comment: Note to self: If information is free flowing, then these cognitive biases are likely to exist: https://betterhumans.coach.me/cognitive-bias-cheat-sheet-55a472476b18#.5nl0ohu45

Answer (score 4):

This depends how deep you want reality to be controlled. 
If it's something like the matrix/brain in a jar you may need a character to philosophically identify inconsistencies in reality.

If it's more of a real world big brother situation, having a good understanding of logical fallacy and the scientific method would be the best base.

I would suggest becoming familiar with stuff like the skeptics movement and looking at how they debunk bad science/conspiracy theories. Most propaganda has difficulty functioning if someone can get a hold of the real scope of an issue and has a secondary source of information.

The biggest problem is that if the level of control is complete enough that there is no dissenting view it can be hard to gather data to disprove or begin to question the propaganda.

If you look into the skeptical view of conspiracy theories there are many reasons that governments generally can't have complete enough control to totally control truth without the perversion of truth being obvious to people who care to look into it. There are too many cogs in the machine for information corruption not to at least be discoverable.

[Skeptical Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeptical_movement)

Answer (score 1):

Method one avoidance. Live in a cave or some other place far from civilization and avoid all form of propaganda.

Method two, Propaganda is usually one sided. Find articles or other sources of information that show facts from the opposite view point or show at least show both sides. Then you will be ably to process the propaganda with more objectivity.

Method three: flee the country.